# Loop in SAS until a specific keyword

Tags: loops, sas

I have a dataset in which there is a column that has all the clicks data. There are 12 main keywords and if any of this keywords are found in the data then software should give the result till the stop keyword appears which are "Home" and start keywords as well. And it should be grouped by Id. So for each group it should run and give me the output.

For example:

```
Id column:

 1     a

 1     b

 1     d

 1     g

 1     d



2    a

2     f

2    v

2    b

2    p

2  home
```

The keywords are : `b and f` So the software should start from b and stop whenever it encounters home or b or f and this would be 1st output(b d g d) then it should go to next group again start from F and stop at home or b or f (f v) this will be second output and then it will again start from b and stop if it encounters b,f or home (b,p,home) this will be my 3rd output. My code is able to form the group and also give me the members in each group but it does not stop at the end of the 1st id. For example I am getting the output as : 1st output: b d g d a

I should not get 'a'.

Code is:

```
data want ; 

set have ; 

retain group 0 member 0 ; 

if member then member+1; 

if column in ('b','f') then do;   

member=1;   

group+1; 

end; 

if member then output; 

if column = 'home' then member=0;

run;
```

Comment: I don't get that result when I run your code as-is.  Can you verify that you do?  (I.e., I copy/pasted that to my editor, added the necessary input stuff around the first one...)

Comment: Sorry Joe I just edited the input data now you can try

Comment: So you don't have a `home` for 1, but you want it to detect the ID number changing and stop there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to detect the `id` change, possibly without `home`, then you need to detect `last.id` (or `first.id` could work also, earlier in the step - they'd work the same.)  This tells you when you're on the last row of a particular ID value; it requires using `by` processing.

```
data want ; 

set have ; 

by id;

retain group 0 member 0 ; 

if member then member+1; 

if column in ('b','f') then do;   

member=1;   

group+1; 

end; 

if member then output; 

if column = 'home' or last.id then member=0;  *last.id = last row of that ID;

run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup flag when column in ('b','f','home').

```
data want;
    set have;
    by ID;
    retain flag;
    if first.id then flag=0;
    if column in ('b','f','home') then flag=1;
    if flag^=0  then output;
    if column='home' then flag=0;
 run;
```